# Use section, header & footer tags instead of data-role

Tags: jquery-mobile

Jon Reid in his jQuery Mobile book has a good idea of using html5 tags:

```
<section data-role="page">
<header data-role="header">
<nav data-role="navbar">
<div data-role="content">
<footer data-role="footer">
```

Q: Is it possible for me to get rid of the data-role="page","header","nav", "footer" if I'm using section, header and footer tags?
Maybe I could put a bit of js goodness in before jQuery Mobile loads.

Theoretically, if I added this before loading jQuery Mobile, it would work:

```
$('header').attr('data-role','header');
```

Hmm... I might have to refresh the elements after applying this attribute though.
Or trigger a create method.

Comment: jQm uses the HTML5 data attribute for a lot of the look and feel and functionality. Removing that would break jQM functionality. Now I think you could pull the parts of jQM you needed and do something custom that way? I know there is a download builder in the works but you could also head over to the git repo and download one of the decoupled widgetshttps://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

Comment: Thanks Phill!  What I mean is: could I run something like this before loading jQuery Mobile: $('header').attr('data-role,"header");

Comment: yes but remember the HTML5 data attribute is a custom attribute so you will need to add your own functionality if you're not using jQM. As far as removing the data-role='page' attribute jQM uses this for navigation

Comment: I want to use jQM, but I guess I'm becoming minimalist when it comes to the html.  Why use both the header tag and the data-role="header" attribute?  Why not just make the html look cleaner and kind of do some preprocessing on mobileinit.

Comment: For now there are a few different ways out there to do this, but none seem to be super great.  I would be careful like Phill said about overriding data-role="page" there is view state info that is saved when JQM builds out a page -   You could wrap HTML 5 syntax inside of the divs manually.

Answer (score 2):

I do this before the jQuery Mobile JavaScript:

```
$('section').attr('data-role','page');
$('article').attr('data-role','content');
$('header').attr('data-role','header');
$('nav').attr('data-role','navbar');
$('aside').addClass('ui-li-aside');
$('ul').not('nav > ul').not('.nolst').attr('data-role','listview').attr('data-inset','true');
$('ol').not('nav > ol').attr('data-role','listview').attr('data-inset','true');;
$('a').not('li > a').not('.nobtn').attr('data-role','button');
$('footer').attr('data-role','footer');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to remove data-role="page" (it's necessary for ajax navigation), and for other tags you can run

```
$(":jqmData(role='page')").live('pagebeforecreate', function(){
    var $page=$(this);
    $page.find("header:not([data-role])").attr('data-role', 'header');
    $page.find("nav:not([data-role])").attr('data-role', 'navbar');
    $page.find("footer:not([data-role])").attr('data-role', 'footer');
}
```