# How does jquery mobile inject classes in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am building a jqm/backbone app.
I have this HTML in a backbone template, loaded into a backbone view :

```
<header class="" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
            <h1>Test2</h1><div id="testModelEdit"><br/>testmodeledit</div>
        </header>
```

At first rendering, this shows a grey header. When the view model changes, and so the view renders again the template, the grey background color is lost.

I noticed that at first rendering, the html looks like this :

```
<header class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit ui-header-fixed slidedown" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
            <h1>Test2</h1><div id="testModelEdit"><br/>testmodeledit</div>
        </header>
```

I guess that JQM injected the classes in header and that it doesn't reinject them upon template re-rendering.

How and when does JQM inject those classes and how can I "refresh" this inject when I re-render my template ?

Comment: did you try a .trigger("create"); on your data-role='page'?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but... I really hate jqM.  It's bloated, slow and way too heavy on Javascript for what amounts to a bunch of UI components.

Comment: I agree on JQM, but is there any good alternative for responsive, adaptative orientation-aware mobile layouts ? didn't find any yet

Comment: @MartinvanHaeften thanks, it works ! Please make an answer out of it so that I can validate it !

Comment: I'm glad I helped you out here! Has jqm changed the syntax for headers finally to <header> or was it you?

Comment: Yes and no. They didn't change it but you can use html5 tags. It's more readable, and you can also remove the data-role like stated here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165323/use-section-header-footer-tags-instead-of-data-role if you do not use ajax navigation

Answer (score 1):

use a `.trigger("create");` on your `data-role='page'`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: In a certain way it does, at least it tells "when" JQM adds those classes